# Only allow free shipping if any product of a specific category is also ordered?

Tags: shipping

I want to allow free shipping just in that case if any product of a specific category is also in the cart. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,
use Promotions -> Shopping Cart Rules

In the condition tab set this condition

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true:
    Category  is  51 use your category
```

and in the Action tab check the "free shipping" checkbox

That's all

Comment: How to give free shipping for selected products using sku, could you pls help me at https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/215022/57334