# Shopping Cart Price Rule - By Using selected SKU Free Shipping Not Working?

Tags: magento-1.9, sku, free-shipping

I using default UPS, USPS, FEDEX, DHL Courier services, How can i give selected products sku free shipping, how to do that?

Workout:

Using selected sku's for free shipping not working?

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Note : In localhost its working, Live site not able to work.**

May i know the possibilities of error?

Comment: did you "applied rules" after creating?

Comment: @ShyamKrishnaSreekumar sorry, i just create rules with SKU right, then where i can apply.

Comment: sorry my mistake, apply rules is for catalog price rules. please cross check dates etc. if it is working in local, it should be in server.

Comment: also please set apply to shipping amount as yes.

Comment: @zus, put stop further rules processing to Yes.

Comment: @ShyamKrishnaSreekumar still not working, after enable  shipping amount as yes

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara not working, i did same in localhost, i dont know why its not working in live site.

Comment: also try swapping the conditions in conditions tab and actions tab. Like remove rule from one tab and try. Then try removing the rule from another and try. Same rules applied in both side can cause issues. just try and let me know.

Comment: @zus, change use per customer to 1000, stop further rules processing to YES, Priority to 1

Comment: no @TejabhagavanKollepara its not working, i tried all type of combination, still its not working, may i know the possibilities of error.

Comment: @zus Flush Magento cache(not refresh cache ) and do reindexing on live site

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala No, not wokring, i tried all possible ways last 4 days.

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala How to apply free shipping for selected products using sku, is any other way to that, pls tell me.

Comment: @zus check the answer given by stalinraj. I haven't tried that but I think that may help you.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Magento does not give us the option to assign free shipping to desired items/products. In this example, we will use attribute to add Free Shipping option.

```
1. Let’s add free shipping option to products. Go to Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes:

2. Click Add new attribute.

3. Fill in the Attribute Code field. Select Global for Scope field and choose Dropdown for Catalog Input for Store Owner field:

4. Make sure to select Yes for the following choices to make the free shipping option visible on the front-end and use the attribute for Price Rule Conditions:

5. Click Manage Label/Options from the left sidebar. Give a name for the field under Admin. In this example, we are using Free Shipping:

6. Now we need to assign this new attribute to an attribute set. Go to Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attribute Sets:

7. We will see the Free Shipping attribute in the Unassigned Attributes column to the right. Click and drag the attribute into one of the sections in the left column:

8. To make it function properly, we need to create a free shipping price rule. Go to Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules:

9. Click Add new rule.

10. Give a name and description to the rule, also set the status to Active:

11. Then go to Actions tab in the left sidebar. Select For matching items only for Free shipping field.

   a). Under if ALL of these conditions are TRUE click the plus sign to add a condition. Select Free Shipping from the list.

   b).Then select Yes or is assigned for price rule conditions:   

12. Save the rule. Now we just need to enable free shipping. Go to System > Configuration:

13. Then Sales > Shipping Methods in the left sidebar.

    a). Enable the option and set the Minimum order amount to a very high number, like 9999999999.99:   

14. Now we can go to Catalog > Manage Products and select a product from the list. Then select free shipping attribute. This product will have a free shipping option:

    Now you know how to assign free shipping to specific items in Magento.
```

Reference url: https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-set-up-free-shipping-for-certain-products.html

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sNAm2KiYkwo